# script in public folder invokes index.php

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I have application written in Zend Framework and structure is

```
app/
    application/
    library/
    public/
```

I have php script called test.php under public folder. When I access it via http://localhost/test.php it does index.php code as well. My .htaccess looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It should stop when test.php found, shouldn't it?

Comment: is mod rewrite enabled in httpd.conf?

Comment: yes, it is, it invokes index.php each time I access any file that exists under public folder (even js scripts). When I remove last line from .htaccess it is ok (accessing test.php does not invoke index.php)

Comment: Yo can enable loggin for your site in your virtual host:

RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

maybe that can give you a hint

Comment: Problem solved. Browser looked for favicon.ico what caused problem. Thanks Esteban Petrovich for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing favicon.ico caused invoke index.php. Adding favicon.ico solved problem.